# How to find X valie of a point on an arc?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I have an arc with a start point `(Xs, Ys)` and an end point `(Xe, Ye)`. Also, I know the direction of movement between them, the center point `(Xc, Yc)`, and the radius. Now I have a point on that arc and I know its `(Yp)` value and need to find its `(Xp)` value. It might seem an easy question, but the issue is I have different cases of arcs, so I need a logic that solves all these cases.

Comment: Did you try forming the equation of the circle?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri a circle equation would give me two values of `(Xp)`, right?

Comment: Yes, you will have to reject one value based on the direction of movement between the end points

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the circle is $(x-X_c)^2+(y-Y_c)^2=R^2.$

$\implies X_p=X_c\pm\sqrt{R^2-(Y_p-Y_c)^2}$

Note that you may need to reject one value of $X_p$ depending on the direction of movement between the end points of the arc.

Comment: Thank you, I have to find a way that helps me to reject one of the values. This is because I am writing a code that should solve all the cases.